# Finding the Frequency of Small Oscillations about an Equilibrium Using Effective Potential

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

As the title says, but I'm having a little trouble. The formula that I'm using is

$$\omega = \sqrt{\frac{V''(x)} m}$$

but in the example of the simple pendulum, $V = -mg\ell\cos\theta$, so $V'' = mg\ell\cos\theta$, and evaluated at $\theta = 0$, according to this formula it should be

$$\omega = \sqrt{g\ell}$$

but of course it's actually $\omega = \sqrt{\dfrac g \ell}$

Any thoughts about where I'm going wrong? I presume it's something to do with the small angle approximation made with the simple pendulum but I would have thought that would have been factored in since we're talking about the frequency of *small* oscillations around an equilibrium.

The question I'm working on is a spherical pendulum reduced to an effective system only dependent on $\theta$. I'm trying to find the frequency of small oscillations using the effective potential, is there an easier way to find it?

Answer (score 1):

If you check again your equations you will find that the total energy is
$$
E=m\frac{(ℓ\dot x)^2}2-mgℓ\cos x
$$
To get it to the standard form for you perturbation theory, you need to divide by $mℓ^2$ to get
$$
\frac{E}{mℓ^2}=\frac{\dot x^2}2-\frac{g}{ℓ}\cos x.
$$
Or in other words, the mass you have to divide by in the perturbation formula is the expression $mℓ^2$ for the pendulum equation.